# Is there a way to check what data is stored in cache?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In case device has no active internet connection and offline persistence is enabled. Is it possible to know what data (collection/document) is cached in the current device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the normal query API, but tell it to use only locally cached data instead of using the server.  This is described in the documentation about [source options](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#source_options).  You will want to pass a source option that indicates cache only.

Comment: Thank you Doug, I'd probably will not progress far without your support :-)